# assign static ttyUSB

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have 2 USB devices connected to raspberry pi,

1. CP2108 USB to serial converter which has 4 ports, when I connect to usb I get 4 ttyUSBx
2. EC25 GSM modem, for this also same case. when I connect I get 4 ports.

How do I assign a static name to all of them?

I have used bellow method but no result.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c7c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0125", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB_EC25_Modem_%s{devpath}"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea71", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB_CP2108X_%s{devpath}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect the devices and look under `/dev/serial/by-id/`. You should have symlinks to these ttyUSBx devices with longer and more descriptive names. No need to use udev rules.

Comment: Much easier solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After hours of searching this was the only viable solution without needing to do any weird checks against the product or vendor ids (which unfortunately if you use the same FTDI usb converter will be identical.